# Extrair dados de um formulário HTML com PHP e escrever Json

Tags: php, html, json, dom

Olá, pessoal. Estou tentando pegar com PHP informações de uma tabela em HTML que está em um site, porém não estou conseguindo separar os dados extraídos. Minha intenção é gerar um arquivo Json com essas informações separadas de acordo com cada linha e tag HTML da tabela.

Segue a tabela e o código que fiz usando `explode`.

```html
<ul class="milestones">
    <li>
        <img src="https://imagem.png">
        <span class="out">04/08/2020 10:09</span>
        <strong>Entrega</strong>
        <br>
        IPATINGA/MG
        <br>
        <small>3 semanas</small>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="https://imagem.png">
        <span class="out">04/08/2020 10:09</span>
        <strong>Entrega</strong>
        <br>
        SÃO PAULO/SP
        <br>
        <small>3 semanas</small>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="https://imagem.png">
        <span class="out">04/08/2020 10:09</span>
        <strong>Entrega</strong>
        <br>
        GOIANIA/GO
        <br>
        <small>3 semanas</small>
    </li>
</ul>
```

```
<?php
  $url = 'https://meusite.com.br/tabela';
  $dadosSite = file_get_contents($url);

  $var1 = explode('<ul class="milestones">',$dadosSite);
  $var2 = explode('</ul>',$var1[1]);

  $var3 = explode('<li>',$var2[0]);
  $var4 = explode('</li>',$var3[1]);

  $dados_json = json_encode($var3[1]);
  $fp = fopen("dados.json", "a");
  $escreve = fwrite($fp, $dados_json);
  fclose($fp);
?>
```

A ideia do arquivo Json é ficar assim:

```
[
  {"imagem":"https://imagem.png","data_hora":"04/08/2020 10:09","titulo":"Entrega", "sub_titulo":"IPATINGA/MG", "semanas":"3 semanas"},
  {"imagem":"https://imagem.png","data_hora":"04/08/2020 10:09","titulo":"Entrega", "sub_titulo":"SÃO PAULO/SP", "semanas":"3 semanas"},
  {"imagem":"https://imagem.png","data_hora":"04/08/2020 10:09","titulo":"Entrega", "sub_titulo":"GOIANIA/GO", "semanas":"3 semanas"},
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que uma solução melhor é fazer um parser do html com [DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.domdocument.php) e [DOMXPath](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.domxpath.php).

O DOMDocument nos permite gerar um objeto manipulável a partir de um documento DOM, nesse caso o HTML, poderia ser um XML também.

O DOMXPath permite usar filtros de pesquisa parecidos com os seletores do CSS retornando nós do documento que podem ser manipulados.

Uma sugestão seria a função html_to_array no exemplo de código a seguir, note que considerei que você está lendo um HTML completo (com Html, Head e Body tags).

```
<?php
$html = '
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<ul class="milestones">
    <li>
        <img src="https://imagem.png">
        <span class="out">04/08/2020 10:09</span>
        <strong>Entrega</strong>
        <br>
        IPATINGA/MG
        <br>
        <small>3 semanas</small>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="https://imagem.png">
        <span class="out">04/08/2020 10:09</span>
        <strong>Entrega</strong>
        <br>
        SÃO PAULO/SP
        <br>
        <small>3 semanas</small>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="https://imagem.png">
        <span class="out">04/08/2020 10:09</span>
        <strong>Entrega</strong>
        <br>
        GOIANIA/GO
        <br>
        <small>3 semanas</small>
    </li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
';

function html_to_array($html, $json_encode) {
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML($html);
    
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

    $tags = $xpath->query('//ul[@class="milestones"]/li');

    $array = [];

    foreach ($tags as $tag) {
      $linha = [];

      $itens = $tag->childNodes;

      $linha['imagem'] = trim($itens->item(1)->getAttribute('src'));
      $linha['data_hora'] = trim($itens->item(2)->nodeValue);      
      $linha['titulo'] = trim($itens->item(4)->nodeValue);
      $linha['sub_titulo'] = trim($itens->item(7)->nodeValue);
      $linha['semanas'] = trim($itens->item(9)->nodeValue);

      $array[] = $linha;
    }
    
    if ($json_encode) {
      return json_encode($array);
    }

    return $array;
}

var_dump(html_to_array($html, false));
```

*Note* que criei uma sugestão bem "rígida" de parser, pensando exatamente no código que enviou do html, por isso as linhas com `$itens->item(1)` definem uma posição específica de itens filhos do no LI que está sendo lido.

Um exemplo de resultado do código executado:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [imagem] => https://imagem.png
            [data_hora] => 04/08/2020 10:09
            [titulo] => Entrega
            [sub_titulo] => IPATINGA/MG
            [semanas] => 3 semanas
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [imagem] => https://imagem.png
            [data_hora] => 04/08/2020 10:09
            [titulo] => Entrega
            [sub_titulo] => SÃO PAULO/SP
            [semanas] => 3 semanas
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [imagem] => https://imagem.png
            [data_hora] => 04/08/2020 10:09
            [titulo] => Entrega
            [sub_titulo] => GOIANIA/GO
            [semanas] => 3 semanas
        )

)
```

Observe que a sequência de posição dos itens possui "saltos", pois cada elemento é um nó dentro da árvore DOM, inclusive as tags BR e textos nos nós.

Acesse a documentação no MDN para compreender melhor sobre [DOM - Modelo de Objeto de Documentos](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/DOM/Referencia_do_DOM)

Comment: Perfeito! Dessa forma mesmo que eu pretendia, porém a tabela HTML está em um site fora do servidor, como ficaria para capturar usando a URL do site? Obrigado pela sua resolução!

Comment: Uma maneira seria pegar o conteúdo com file_get_contents(url) .... agradeço se marcar a resposta como escolhida, esta é a forma da comunidade identificar as soluções encontradas para os problemas levantados